# Android: Gridview Image Gallery in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, image-gallery

Want to build a image gridview in a fragment, but the app crashes, when this fragment gets active.
Tutorial was [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android).
MainActivity opens the following. Other Files were copy paste:

```
public class ImageActivity extends Fragment {
private GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpaper, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_wallpaper_item, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

// Prepare some dummy data for gridview
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
    }
    return imageItems;
}}
```

Comment: Just found out, that it works with other images in the array. So I have to make some thumbnails.

Comment: It looks like there are Limits to the Size of the images. Do you know where this comes from?